# Identify which company a news article is about

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

We have a task of identifying which company a news article is about. The input is a (business) news article, the goal is the company name.

Could recommend a solution, please?

At the moment, we start with finding the N most mentioned company names in the article (by a Named Entity Recognition algorithm). When N >= 2, NER results can give us >75% accuracy. But when N = 1, this only give us about 50% accuracy.